# SelectedKeys doesn't remove socketChannel and Selector select it every time

Tags: java, selector, nio

I wrote simple echo-client and selector every time select SocketChannel as readable.
I got EOF if I try to read this socketChannel.

I removed SelectedKey from selector.selectedKeys(). What's the problem with selector?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Selector selector = Selector.open();

            SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

            socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_WRITE | SelectionKey.OP_READ);
            socketChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 2000));

            System.out.println("start eventloop");

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("echo\n".getBytes());
            int i = 0;
            while(true) {
                try{
                    if(i++==10) break;
                    selector.select();
                    System.out.println("events: " + selector.selectedKeys().size());
                    Iterator<SelectionKey> it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

                    while(it.hasNext()) {
                        SelectionKey selectionKey = it.next();
                        SocketChannel channel = (SocketChannel)selectionKey.channel();

                        if(selectionKey.isConnectable()) {
                            System.out.println("connectable");
                            try{
                                channel.finishConnect();
                                System.out.println("connected " + channel.getLocalAddress() + " <> " + channel.getRemoteAddress());
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                channel.close();
                            }
                        }
                        if(selectionKey.isReadable()) {
                            System.out.println("readable");
                            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
                            buffer.clear();
                            int x = channel.read(buffer);
                            if(x > 0) {
                                buffer.flip();
                                System.out.println("server> " + Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buffer).toString());
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("EOF");
                            }
                        }
                        if(selectionKey.isWritable()) {
                            System.out.println("writeable");
                            channel.write(byteBuffer);
                            byteBuffer.flip();
                            channel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                        }
                        it.remove();
                    }
                    System.out.println("not handled events:" + selector.selectedKeys().size());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }
            }
            selector.close();
            socketChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

STDOUT:

```
start eventloop
events: 1
connectable
connected /127.0.0.1:65283 <> localhost/127.0.0.1:2000
not handled events:0
events: 1
writeable
not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
server> echo

not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
EOF
not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
EOF
not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
EOF
not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
EOF
not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
EOF
not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
EOF
not handled events:0
events: 1
readable
EOF
not handled events:0
```

Answer (score 0):

It does remove it, but it just keeps reappearing, because OP_WRITE is almost always ready, because the socket send buffer almost always has room in it. You should only register for this event when you've encountered a zero length write, and you should deregister as soon as a write prompted by OP_WRITE has succeeded.